Why does Eclipse throw a StackOverflowError every time it tries to validate my project?
When I select Project > Clean > [my_project], it gets about 40% through validation and consistently throws a StackOverflow error due to what appears to be infinite recursion after accessing a JavaServer Faces source file, "LoadBundleUtil". Curiously, eclipse seems to be calling this class with itself. Here's the relevant section of the .metadata/.log file:
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2024-08-21 08:30:11.223
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Validating my_project".
!STACK 0
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path.<init>(Path.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path.<init>(Path.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.internal.tld.LoadBundleUtil.getFilePath(LoadBundleUtil.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.internal.tld.LoadBundleUtil.getFile(LoadBundleUtil.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.internal.tld.LoadBundleUtil.getSourceFile(LoadBundleUtil.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.internal.tld.LoadBundleUtil.getSourceFile(LoadBundleUtil.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.internal.tld.LoadBundleUtil.getSourceFile(LoadBundleUtil.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.internal.tld.LoadBundleUtil.getSourceFile(LoadBundleUtil.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.internal.tld.LoadBundleUtil.getSourceFile(LoadBundleUtil.java:86)
[repeats for over 100 more times]

I'm using Eclipse 2024-06, and JavaServer Faces 2.3
If anyone has ideas on how to fix this, I'd appreciate it.

It could just be an Eclipse bug, but you can try doubling the stack space and see if it helps. Somewhere in the Eclipse configuration file will be a setting for the options used to launch the JVM process.

Can you please provide a [mcve]?

This may be the same problem as https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=560833

Could you have cyclic dependencies between this project and another one? Is it part of an EAR? It's not doing anything weird like having itself on its own Java Build Path, is it? And, of course, which version of Eclipse are you on?

I've tried increasing the stack space in eclipse.ini:
-Xms4096m
-Xmx4096m
Validation still fails

This does look similar to the linked bug, I'll work on making an MRE. I wouldn't be surprised if there are cyclic dependency issues, there was a warning related to that when I first pulled the repo. I believe it's part of a WAR, not an EAR, but I'm still new to Java so I could be wrong. I don't see it in its own Build Path under Modulepath or Classpath. I'm on Eclipse 2024-06.

Be sure to retry this with 2024-09, when released.

I can confirm that the project does include circular dependencies (projects used by my_project use each other's classes) -- could that be causing this issue? Or is Eclipse smart enough to handle this? I know the ideal would be to refactor out the circular dependencies but that's a long-term goal.

In Eclipse 2024-09 the error seems fixed (validation eventually completes without StackOverflowError being thrown), although validation is still very slow
